# How to make phonegap app run even after it is removed from recent list?

Tags: cordova, webview, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I am building an app which has to check a website every 5 minutes. I need to ensure that even if the user removes the app from their recent apps' list in Android, my app can still check that website every 5 minutes.

I found this:
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

and some other plugins but they stop working if the app is removed from the user's recent apps' list.

What is the easiest way to do this in Phonegap/Cordova ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a **background service** to accomplish that, [read this](https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core/wiki/Build-your-own-Background-Service)

Comment: Is there some ready made plugin for this ? As I am new to app develpoment and have limited experience in Java, do you some way I can get this already made ?